# Focus() and blur() triggers together for firefox when displaying a canvas

Tags: firefox, canvas, display, area

I have area and canvas elements. Initially canvas element is set to `display:none`. When focus on area element, adding a class to canvas for `dispaly:block`. On blur() of area, removing that class from canvas. In Chrome, it is working fine.But in firefox, focus() and blur() events triggers together. So, unable to disaply the canvas. Also when area is focused, we can press Enter key to select the area.

Do anyone know is this known issue for Firefox or any fix will resolve this issue?

Tried with different ways. Like, setTimeout, using show() and hide() for canvas, trigger focus() on blur() of area element for firefox.

If using setTimeout on focus, Enter key does not selecting the area.

So, did not work any solutions perfectly.

Thanks in advance